# Assign enum an enums value

Tags: java, enums

I want to assign an enum an enum value like

enum 1

```
public enum e1{
    value1, 
    value2;
}
```

enum 2

```
public enum e2{
    val1 ( some value from e1 ), 
    val2 ( some value from e1 );
}
```

I should also be able to change the value of `val1` later depending on the conditions.

How is that possible in Java?

Comment: You cannot change enums. That's why they are enums...

Comment: This question is very vague at the moment - particularly the "I should also be able to change the value of val1" - what do you mean?

Answer (score 7):

Enums are basically classes in Java, so you can just make a property:

```
public enum E2 {
  VAL1(E1.VALUE1),
  VAL2(E2.VALUE2);

  public final E1 e1Value;

  E2(E1 e1Value) {
    this.e1Value = e1Value;
  }
}
```

You *could* also make a getter/setter for `e1Value`, but I'd **strongly** discourage this. While nothing technically stops you from making a modifyable field in an enum, it is highly unusual and unexpected and *will* lead to confusing and/or subtle bugs.

Comment: Can I also change the value of VAL1 from E1.VALUE1 to E2.VALUE2 ? If yes then how?

Comment: @AbhishekGoel: Did you even read the last paragraph? The one that is *not code*? You could do it by writing a setter (and making `e1Value` non-final), just as you would with any other class. **But**, it's a really bad idea. If you need a *mutable* binding between two enums, then you're probably better of keeping track of that in a map somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
public enum E1 {
    A, B;
}
```

and then:

```
public enum E2 {
    C(E1.A), D(E1.B);

    private final E1 e1;

    private E2(E1 e1) {
        this.e1 = e1;
    }

    public E1 getE1() {
        return e1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have a member variable in an Enum if you provide a constructor :

```
    public enum e2{
        A2(e1.B1),
        B2(e1.B1),
        C2(e1.A1);

        e1 e1Value;

        e2(e1 e1NewValue){
            e1Value = e1NewValue;
        }
    }

    public enum e1{
        A1, B1;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Mutable enum, ouch. Technically possible, but i'd advise against it. If its just one time value at the time of intialization, its perfectly fine and good.

```
public enum e1{
        value1("1"), 
        value2("2");

        String val;
        private e1(String v) {
            val = v;
        }

        //bad don't use
        public void setValue(String v){
            val = v;
        }

        public String getValue(){
            return val;
        }
    }
//usage
e1.value1.setValue("3");
e1.value1.setValue("4");
```